# Patrón de diseño con una clase y 2 subclases pero sin usar herencia

Tags: java, herencia, patrones-de-diseño

Necesito implementar una clase y 2 subclases en la que la clase principal contenga el *id* y se lo envíe a las 2 subclases, pero la primera subclase puede cambiar el valor del *id* y debe saberlo la clase principal ya que tiene que estar actualizado para usar los métodos de búsqueda de la segunda subclase. No puedo usar herencia porque las subclases no pueden estar ancladas a la clase principal, porque mas adelante dichas subclases las usaré con otras clases superiores. Creo que tengo que usar interfaces pero no me queda claro.

Aquí dejo el código de muestra.

```
//Main principal
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PanelPrincipal panel = PanelPrincipal(20);
        }
    }

    //Panel principal

    public class PanelPrincipal {
        int id;

        public PanelGeneralController(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    //Subpanel Persona
        public class SubPanelPersona {
            int id;

            public SubPanelPersona() { }

            public void cambiarValor() {
                this.id = 30;
            }
        }

    //Subpanel Socio
        public class SubPanelSocio {
            int id;

            public SubPanelSocio() {}

            public void buscarSocio() {
                //Método el cual buscará en la base de datos el socio con ese id.
                buscar(id);
            }
        }
```

Lo que busco es que esa variable cuando la recibe la clase principal la envíe a las 2 subclases cuando las instancie, una vez tengan las variables las subclases por ejemplo SubPanelPersona cambia el valor de dicha clase, entones tiene que recibirlo PanelPrincipal y mandárselo a la subclase SubPanelSocio porque cuando busque el id en la base de datos habrá cambiado el id desde la otra subclase, me imagino que tendré que usar un Observer en la clase principal pero no lo tengo bien claro

Comment: A la pregunta le esta faltando que es lo que queres lograr con esto. Vos pensaste una solución y te encontraste con un problema que no te deja avanzar. Tal vez el problema sea la soución elegida y haya otra forma mas simple de lograr lo que querés hacer.

Comment: Una opción sería guardar una referencia a la clase principal en la subclase, y una vez se cambie el valor id de la subclase puedes usar esa referencia para notificar a la clase principal. Si quieres buscar más sobre como hacer eso te recomiendo buscar información del patrón Observer.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Juan. Creo que si estás bloqueado en este punto es porque quizá debes repensar tu modelo de datos. Si explicas un poco lo que quieres hacer quizá podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Tal y como describes el prolema, tengo la duda de si las llamadas son sincronas o asincronas. Si son sincronas, el patron de diseño composite debe ser suficiente para resolver el problema, ya que llamarias a la segunda "subclase" despues de llamar a la primera y recoger el valor de vuelta, por lo que el ID siempre estaría actualizado. Por otro lado, en el caso asincrono, se me asemeja mucho a un patron observer o una arquitectura orientada a eventos. Veras, tal como lo cuentas entiendo que hay una "subclase" puede cambiar el valor de un atributo ID, del que debe enterarse la clase "padre", o l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la idea que estaba buscando, no sé si es mejorable para hacerlo con menos código, yo por ahora necesito un panel (es para hacer una interfaz ) donde voy a tener que implementar 7 subclases pero mas adelante necesitaré otro panel donde quiero aprovechar 3 subclases.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class PanelLibros {
    int id;
    SubPanelPersona subPanelPersona = new SubPanelPersona(this);
    SubPanelSocio subPanelSocio = new SubPanelSocio(this);

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
}

class PanelVideos {
    int id;
    SubPanelPersona subPanelPersona = new SubPanelPersona(this);
    SubPanelSocio subPanelSocio = new SubPanelSocio(this);

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
}

class SubPanelPersona {
    private PanelLibros panelLibros;
    private PanelVideos panelVideos;

    public SubPanelPersona(PanelLibros panelLibros) {
        this.panelLibros = panelLibros;
    }

    public SubPanelPersona(PanelVideos panelVideos) {
        this.panelVideos = panelVideos;
    }

    public void cambiarValorLibros(int id) { this.panelLibros.setId(id); }
    public void cambiarValorVideos(int id) { this.panelVideos.setId(id); }
}

class SubPanelSocio {
    private PanelLibros panelLibros;
    private PanelVideos panelVideos;

    public SubPanelSocio(PanelLibros panelLibros) {
        this.panelLibros = panelLibros;
    }
    public SubPanelSocio(PanelVideos panelVideos) {
        this.panelVideos = panelVideos;
    }

    public void buscarSocioLibros() { System.out.println("Buscando ID: " + this.panelLibros.id); }
    public void buscarSocioVideos() { System.out.println("Buscando ID: " + this.panelVideos.id); }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    PanelLibros panelLibros = new PanelLibros();
    PanelVideos panelVideos = new PanelVideos();

}
```

Comment: ¿Esto soluciona tu problema? Si es así, déjalo como respuesta, de lo contrario, no. La verdad, tu código quedó muy redundante. Si pudieras editar la pregunta y especificar con **claridad** el problema, te pudiera ayudar de una mejor forma.

Comment: He editado mi primera cuestión para explicarlo con mas claridad @MrDave1999, espero que te sea de ayuda, también por otro lado me han recomendado que use el patrón Observer pero no me ha quedado claro del todo, por eso preguntaba si con el patrón Observer evitaría tanta redundancia.

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: Quiero montar un ejemplo con el patrón observer a ver si puedo desacoplar el panel principal de los subpaneles pero ando muy liado con otra cosa y no puedo hacerlo, en cuanto pueda lo expongo, gracias por tu ejemplo, me vino bien de ayuda pero no es la solución exacta que estoy buscando

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no comprendo muy bien el problema que quieres resolver, me queda claro que no lo puedes resolver con herencia, por lo tanto que llames a los SubPaneles con el término "subclase" me confunde. Tal vez quisiste decir clase interna. En fin, te muestro dos formas de lograr lo que creo que quieres hacer:

**1 - Inyectando el mismo PanelPrincipal en los dos SubPaneles, cuando cambias el valor desde un SubPanel, el otro SubPanel accede a la misma variable con el valor actualizado:**

```
class PanelPrincipal {
    int id;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class SubPanelPersona {
    private PanelPrincipal panelPrincipal;

    public SubPanelPersona(PanelPrincipal panelPrincipal) {
        this.panelPrincipal = panelPrincipal;
    }

    public void cambiarValor(int id) {
        this.panelPrincipal.setId(id);
    }
}

class SubPanelSocio {
    private PanelPrincipal panelPrincipal;

    public SubPanelSocio(PanelPrincipal panelPrincipal) {
        this.panelPrincipal = panelPrincipal;
    }

    public void buscarSocio() {
        System.out.println("Buscando ID: " + this.panelPrincipal.id);
    }
}
```

Lo usas así:

```
PanelPrincipal panelPrincipal = new PanelPrincipal();
SubPanelPersona subPanelPersona = new SubPanelPersona(panelPrincipal);
SubPanelSocio subPanelSocio = new SubPanelSocio(panelPrincipal);

subPanelPersona.cambiarValor(9);
subPanelSocio.buscarSocio();
subPanelPersona.cambiarValor(3);
subPanelSocio.buscarSocio();
```

**2 - Con clases internas estáticas:**

```
class PanelPrincipal {
    private static int id;

    static class SubPanelPersona {
        public void cambiarValor(int valor) {
            id = valor;
        }
    }

    static class SubPanelSocio {
        public void buscarSocio() {
            System.out.println("Buscando ID: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo usas así:

```
PanelPrincipal.SubPanelPersona subPanelPersona = new PanelPrincipal.SubPanelPersona();
PanelPrincipal.SubPanelSocio subPanelSocio = new PanelPrincipal.SubPanelSocio();

subPanelPersona.cambiarValor(9);
subPanelSocio.buscarSocio();
subPanelPersona.cambiarValor(3);
subPanelSocio.buscarSocio();
```

Comment: La solución es buena, pero me falta una duda, que hacer cuando las 2 subclases (clases internas) tenga que usarlas en otras clases, voy a compartir un código para saber si sería correcto así.

Answer (score 1):

> > Patrón de diseño con una clase y 2 subclases pero sin usar herencia

Podemos modelar la clase `PanelPrincipal` de esta forma:

```java
public class PanelPrincipal 
{
     private int id;

     public void setId(int id)
     {
        this.id = id;
     }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public PanelPrincipal(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Posteriormente, la clase `SubPanelPersona` tendrá un constructor parametrizado, en la cual, recibirá la referencia de un objeto de tipo `PanelPrincipal`.

```java
public class SubPanelPersona 
{
      public SubPanelPersona(PanelPrincipal panel) 
      { 
          panel.setId(30);
      }
}
```

Y por último, la clase `SubPanelSocio`, tendrá el método `buscarSocio` con un parámetro, en la cual, recibe la id del socio.

```java
public class SubPanelSocio 
{       
    public buscarSocio(int id)
    {
       //Método el cual buscará en la base de datos el socio con ese id.
        buscar(id);
    }
}
```

El uso de cada clase sería de esta forma:

```java
public class App 
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          var panel = new PanelPrincipal(20);
          var spanelPers = new SubPanelPersona(panel);
          new SubPanelSocio().buscar(panel.getId());

          System.out.println(panel.getId());
     }
}
```

El bloque de sentencias de arriba hace lo siguiente:

- Crea un objeto de tipo `PanelPrincipal`, luego se ejecuta el constructor y la variable `id` queda inicializada en `20`.
- Se crea un objeto de tipo `SubPanelPersona`, se pasa la referencia al constructor y la variable `id` (del objeto al que apunte `panel`) cambia su valor a `30`.
- Se crea la instancia y se pasa el valor actualizado al método `buscar` de la clase `SubPanelSocio`.
- Al final, el resultado por pantalla debería ser `30` (valor actualizado).